# How can I send emails to multiple recipients?

Tags: php, mysql, email

My request form is taking to much time to submit. Also sometimes the emails are repeated and in error log I can see this PHP Warning:  `mail() [<a href='function.mail'>function.mail</a>]: Could not execute mail delivery program '/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i'` 
Here is my code:

```
    $emails = mysql_query('select * from owners where status ="active"');

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($emails)){

        $to = $row['s_email'];
        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From: mysitename  <noreply@mysitename.com' . "\r\n";
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    }
```

Comment: Your `From` address is malformed

Answer (score 1):

To send an email to multiple recipients, separate each email address by a comma. Instead of a loop, you can do this in one line with the `implode()` function.

To answer your question, it could be a memory leak. Try my solution replacing your code with mine:

```
$emails = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM owners WHERE status = 'active'");
$emails->execute()->fetchAll();

mail(implode(', ', $emails), $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Also, please avoid using `mysql_*` functions. They're deprecated. Try `PDO` instead. More information can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

---

You may also want to look into cron jobs. Emails sent with the `mail()` function are often automatically placed in the spam folder.

Comment: It is true, but it don't think it will solve the error message "Could not execute mail delivery program '/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i'"

Comment: Oh, sorry. The title mislead me. Perhaps that should be changed. I'll edit my answer in a mo.

Comment: can i try your above code -MR.terry harvey

Comment: But in 'to' it shows all the emails id's how can i hide it or can i use cc ?

Comment: @user168818 Use the BCC header.